# Does Thunderwave normally deal falling damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, falling

Is normal that if a target is Thunderwave'd into a wall, then they take initial damage from the Spell, and then *additional* "falling damage" from being flung into the wall.

Similarly, if there's an object (say, a cart) between the target at the caster, would it be normal for the target to get hit by the cart and be dealt additional damage as a result?

I can't find anything in RAW that explicitly covers it either way, and obviously the DM can Rule Zero whatever they want. But would doing so be considered *normal*?